# simple json response makes me nuts

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, parsing, jsonp

I want to parse json to javascript object

this is the json response:

```
{"Response":{"balance":"ERROR: address invalid","difficulty":"230.888","price":"0.000456","24hAgo":"0.000427","percentage":94,"mtprice":"880.85","bestmarket":"example","volume":"68","markt":69,"rank":16}}

$.ajax({
url:"example.html",
type:'GET',
dataType:'JSONP',
success: function(data){

console.log(data) // returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
var parser = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(parser); // returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

}
});
```

What is wrong here ? I am trying to get the price into a javascript variable but because of the error it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that that JSON string is the complete response? You can use Firebug in Firefox to see what comes back from the call.

Comment: this is the whole response (i made the json response i am trying to catch it on another website) this is the only code i use on the page... and i added jquery so i can use jquery

Comment: Something is different -- that JSON at the top is valid.

Comment: But use firebug and see what is actually being returned because it may not be what you expect.

Comment: JSON seems to be valid.I checked it on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: that is the only response from the website...and the code you see above is my only code

Comment: You should add the other 2 parameters to the `success` callback and look at the response code and the headers - are you getting back something unexpected (different content-type?)

Comment: Joe can you give me an example i don't know how to add others i tried error but it gives me the same error

Comment: It has to do with the same origin policy maybe because when i use JSON it does not work but when i use jSONP it works only it gives that error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when your server responds with JSON and your Ajax call want JSONP (because of the same origin policy trouble)

I used this little "hack" to support json and jsonp...

http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
$json = json_encode($data);

echo isset($_GET['callback'])
? "{$_GET['callback']}($json)"
: $json;
?>
```

So just add &callback to the link if you use JSONP and if not just use the link..